# height:auto causes white space at the bottom in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

html code

```
<nav>...</nav>
<div class="bg">
      <div class="outer-box">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <div class="dev-image">
            <img
              src="img/ronak-dev-ux-ui-design-project-image@3x.webp"
              alt="Profile Picture"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="dev-name">Ronak Radadiya</div>
          <div class="dev-profession">Lorem Ipsum</div>
          <div class="dev-content">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi sed cumque voluptatem repudiandae illo dolor nihil, ducimus eaque voluptatibus ex perspiciatis deleniti corrupti repellendus reiciendis rem expedita laudantium, velit dicta?
          </div>
          <div class="reach">
            <img
              src="img/ronak-dev-ux-ui-design-line@3x.webp"
              alt="Reach out"
            />
            <p>Reach Out to me</p>
            <img
              src="img/ronak-dev-ux-ui-design-line@3x.webp"
              alt="Reach out"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="social-icons">
            <a
              href="#"
              target="_blank"
            >
              <img
                src="img/ronak-whatsapp-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="whatsapp"
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://github.com/ronakradadiya" target="_blank">
              <img
                src="img/ronak-github-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="github"
              />
            </a>

            <a
              href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ronak-radadiya-506861167"
              target="_blank"
            >
              <img
                src="img/ronak-linkedin-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="Linkedin"
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/ronakradadiya98" target="_blank">
              <img
                src="img/ronak-twitter-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="twitter"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<footer>... </footer>
```

css code

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Navbar */

.actives {
  color: #ff4060 !important;
}

.active {
  color: #ff4060 !important;
}

nav.bg-dark {
  background-color: var(--main-bg1-color) !important;
  height: 53px !important;
}

nav.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}

nav .nav-color {
  color: var(--main-text-color) !important;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-family: ProximaNovaA;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  margin: 0rem 0.6rem;
}

/* Introduction */

.bg {
  height: calc(100% - 117px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixedHeight {
  height: 507px;
}

.autoHeightBody {
  height: auto;
}

.autoHeightBg {
  height: auto;
}

.outer-box {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--main-bg1-color);
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.dev-image {
  max-width: 96px;
  max-height: 96px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.dev-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dev-name {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.dev-profession {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.58px;
  color: #ff4060;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.dev-content {
  max-width: 545px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aeaeae;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.reach {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.reach img {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.reach img:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.reach p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 41px;
}

.social-icons img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.social-icons img:nth-child(1),
.social-icons img:nth-child(2),
.social-icons img:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-adjust {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-left-content p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.footer-right-content {
  display: flex;
}

.footer-right-content div a {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-right-content div:nth-child(1) a,
.footer-right-content div:nth-child(2) a {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .bg {
    height: calc(100% - 161px);
  }

  .outer-box {
    min-height: 507px;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 108px !important;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .footer,
  .footer-adjust {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .footer-left-content p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }

  .footer-right-content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 575px) {
  .bg {
    height: calc(100% - 161px);
  }

  .outer-box {
    min-height: 507px;
  }

  .reach img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 108px !important;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .footer-right-content div:nth-child(1) a,
  .footer-right-content div:nth-child(2) a {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  .footer,
  .footer-adjust {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .footer-left-content p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }

  .footer-right-content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

JS code

```
let styleBgBox = parseInt($(".bg").css("height"));
let styleOuterBox = parseInt($(".outer-box").css("height"));

if ($(window).outerWidth() >= 768) {
  $(".outer-box").addClass("fixedHeight");
} else {
  $(".outer-box").removeClass("fixedHeight");
}

if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox == 507) {
  $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
} else if (styleBgBox > 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
  $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
} else if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
  $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
} else {
  $("body").removeClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").removeClass("autoHeightBg");
}

$(window).resize(function () {
  if ($(window).outerWidth() >= 768) {
    $(".outer-box").addClass("fixedHeight");
  } else {
    $(".outer-box").removeClass("fixedHeight");
  }

  styleBgBox = parseInt($(".bg").css("height"));
  styleOuterBox = parseInt($(".outer-box").css("height"));
  if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox == 507) {
    $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
  } else if (styleBgBox > 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
    $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
  } else if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
    $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").removeClass("autoHeightBg");
  }
});
```

When I replace the existing height which is calculated using calc() with height:auto, a white space at the bottom appears when viewed in mobile devices. Is there any alternative to height:auto to be used in the code. I tried using vh instead of %, using overflow property, but it didn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are the problem

```
html {height: 100%;}
body {height: 100%;}
```

100% height of html and body is a heigh of a viewport, and not a whole document. Inner elements made the common height more then viewport and it could make the whitspases you are taking about.

**UPDATED**

Remove your custom `script` at all. I will write down only CSS classes, i made changes in. Replace and it will work.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #111111;
}
nav.bg-dark {
    background-color: var(--main-bg1-color) !important;
    height: 53px !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.bg {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 53px 0 60px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #111111;
    height: 64px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .bg {
    padding: 53px 0 156px 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 575px) {
  .bg {
    padding: 53px 0 156px 0;
  }  
}
```

Comment: When I use min-height:100% on html and body and when I removed js code, it is working fine on mobile devices, but white space appears at the bottom in large devices like desktop screen.

Comment: On large screens, I want the content to be visible within the viewport meaning no scrollbar should be introduced unless and until it is viewed in smaller devices, then can I introduce scrollbar. This is what I want

Comment: Try just to add html {min-height: 100%;}
body {min-height: 100%;} and don’t remove js. If this doesn’t help - i will go on with looking for a solution

Comment: Still causing the same issue as mentioned earlier

Comment: Is there a live demo site? I'd like to see a whole code of the page.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Can u tell me more about the diff of viewport and document ?

Comment: For the best experience first of all use `html {height: 100%;} body {min-height: 100%; position: relative;}`, i had a mistake in my first answer. Use these construction in every project. Although read a little about `position absolute` inside `reletive`. 100vh - is 100% of a current viewport (all you can see on your screen).  Sometimes it's a little bit unstable on mobile browsers while you scrolling and the height of a browser changing dynamically due to navbars hiding/appearing

Comment: Is it possible that you can help me out with one last thing ?

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can ask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780016/in-mobile-devices-using-chrome-in-android-when-i-scroll-down-the-modal-and-the?noredirect=1#comment109296973_61780016.  Here is the link.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `height` attribute from each `.bg` in the css portion (I counted 3 total).
Also remove `min-height: 507px;` from both `.outer-box` in css.

Change your `html` and `body` css to read as follows. This will ensure your elements are encompassed by your body tag, and body by html tag:

```
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I tried your code with the modifications I mentioned, with and without your JS, and it didn't seem to make a difference. It doesn't seem like your JS is really required if you use the modification to css and are wanting to remove the white space at bottom of your page. See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s97htk0p/

Your modified CSS code:

```
html,body{

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Navbar */

.actives {
  color: #ff4060 !important;
}

.active {
  color: #ff4060 !important;
}

nav.bg-dark {
  background-color: var(--main-bg1-color) !important;
  height: 53px !important;
}

nav.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}

nav .nav-color {
  color: var(--main-text-color) !important;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-family: ProximaNovaA;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  margin: 0rem 0.6rem;
}

/* Introduction */

.bg {

  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixedHeight {
  height: 507px;
}

.autoHeightBody {
  height: auto;
}

.autoHeightBg {
  height: auto;
}

.outer-box {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--main-bg1-color);
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.dev-image {
  max-width: 96px;
  max-height: 96px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.dev-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dev-name {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.dev-profession {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.58px;
  color: #ff4060;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.dev-content {
  max-width: 545px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aeaeae;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.reach {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.reach img {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.reach img:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.reach p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 41px;
}

.social-icons img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.social-icons img:nth-child(1),
.social-icons img:nth-child(2),
.social-icons img:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-adjust {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-left-content p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.footer-right-content {
  display: flex;
}

.footer-right-content div a {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-right-content div:nth-child(1) a,
.footer-right-content div:nth-child(2) a {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {


  .footer {
    height: 108px !important;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .footer,
  .footer-adjust {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .footer-left-content p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }

  .footer-right-content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 575px) {




  .reach img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 108px !important;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .footer-right-content div:nth-child(1) a,
  .footer-right-content div:nth-child(2) a {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  .footer,
  .footer-adjust {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .footer-left-content p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }

  .footer-right-content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because it is almost the same answer after a 30 minuts from the first one. Almost a copy. No new ideas to solve a problem.

Comment: I would have to disagree. First post only talked about html and body tags. This answer talks about other portions of the O.P. code. If you did not change the html,body tags but still changed the .bg and min-height in css, problem would still have been fixed. Not sure about the other way around. Correcting if the html,body tags makes sure the content is inside body, but does not fix white space issue.

Comment: May be at some point you are right. If you edit you answer (no matter how) - i could fix my mark (because my vote is locked in unless this answer is edited.)

Comment: @ArjunSethi On large screens, I want the content to be visible within the viewport meaning no scrollbar should be introduced unless and until it is viewed in smaller devices, then can I introduce scrollbar. I hope you got what I meant

Comment: @ArjunSethi For that reason I have used height property in .bg class so that it calculates height accordingly and fits whithin the visible viewport with no scrollbar in large screens.